# Bayesian Networks Representation of p(a,b,c) of Bishop Book

Tags: bayesian, chain-rule, bayesian-network

In Chapter 8 of Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning the joint probability of p(a,b,c) is calculated applying the rule product and Bayes:

p(a,b,c) = p(c|a,b)* p(b|a)*p(a)

But if you apply the same rule we get
p(a,b,c) = p(a|b,c) * p(b|c) * p(c)

First question p(a|b,c) * p(b|c) * p(c) = p(c|a,b)* p(b|a)*p(a) ?

Bishop represents the p(a,b,c) = p(c|a,b)* p(b|a)*p(a) in a Bayesian Network but if you use p(a|b,c) * p(b|c) * p(c) = p(c|a,b)* p(b|a)*p(a) we have other representation. The representation is the same?

[image: Figure representing network]
The representation of the two bayesian networks

Comment: Yes, the equations you wrote are all valid.

Comment: Thanks! But the representation the two equation we get different representations of bayesian networks. It is correct?

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks! But the representation the two equation we get different representations of bayesian networks. It is correct?

Yes.   It will often happen that a joint probability has several distinct factorisations, each of which may be represented by its own signature diagram.

The factorisation $\mathsf P(A,B,C)=\mathsf P(A\mid B,C)\mathsf P(B\mid C)\mathsf P(C)$ would be described by the network

$${C\\\downarrow~\searrow\\ B\to A}$$

The factorisation $\mathsf P(A,B,C)=\mathsf P(A)\mathsf P(B\mid A)\mathsf P(C\mid A,B)$ would be described by the network

$${C\\\uparrow~\nwarrow\\ B\gets A}$$

The factorisation $\mathsf P(A,B,C)=\mathsf P(A\mid B)\mathsf P(B)\mathsf P(C\mid A,B)$ would be described by the network

$${C\\\uparrow~\nwarrow\\ B\to A}$$

And so forth. The graphs describe distinct factorisations, each of which conveys the same basic information about the variables' dependencies, just expressed in a different way.